# Publishing to NPM when verdaccio is installed

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, verdaccio

I installed Verdaccio locally on my Ubuntu machine, and it's been working fine.

Now I'm trying to publish a package to NPM, and so I shut down verdaccio, but I still get this message:

> If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>   npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.

```
npm ERR! FetchError: request to http://localhost:4873/@fireflysemantics%2fvalidator failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4873
```

I assume this is because npm is still trying to publish to the local verdaccio server.  How do we toggle this back to NPM?

I tried doing:

```
npm set registry https://www.npmjs.com
```

And then publishing `@fireflysemantics/validator` but it says it's not in the registry even though it is:

```
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          @fireflysemantics/validator             
npm notice version:       1.1.29                                  
npm notice package size:  55.9 kB                                 
npm notice unpacked size: 485.2 kB                                
npm notice shasum:        79d8ade13ff3b1fa1bc307d28fb3dda3942a2e5d
npm notice integrity:     sha512-jh1PoZeWQRkgm[...]ebRmyadB5CaPA==
npm notice total files:   265                                     
npm notice 
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://www.npmjs.com/@fireflysemantics%2fvalidator
```

I also can't login to NPM.  Tried

```
npm login
```

Email: (this IS public) yyy.dddddd@m.com
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://www.npmjs.com/-/user/org.couchdb.user:oleersoy

```
So NPM is reponding but somehow my client is not talking to it the right way ...
```

Comment: I've done `npm ifo @fireflysemantics/validator` and I'm getting results. Verdaccio is just a web application, I'd suggest you try to see more verbose output using `npm -ddd info @fireflysemantics/validator` and you will see exactly what's happening. If the public registry is returning 404 much likely would be an issue in their side.

Answer (score 4):

To switch back run:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: There are at least 3 ways to interfiere with the default registry, I think the answer might be more complete but also I am sure is duplicated somewhere else.

Comment: I would be nice is NPM just used `npm set registry` to set the registry back to NPMs site ... since that is how we configure local registries like Verdaccio.